# Remove special characters from the specified string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to remove a character from a string in excel. How can I remove the first and last character from the specified string? In excel sheet I have data in every column. Some of the test starting and ending with $$ characters, I need to remove only first character ($) and last character ($) from the string.

Example: Cell 1:

```
$$hello world$$. World is beautiful. $$where there is will there is a way.$$ money makes many things.
```

Should represent:

```
$hello world$. World is beautiful. $where there is will there is a way. $money makes many things$.
```

Thanks All

Comment: Select all the cells where you want to remove the $$ sigh. Hit `CTRL+H` KEY and then Replace `$$` with `$`..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SUBSTITUTE() formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"$$","$")
```

Answer (score 0):

As an non-formulaic alternative would be to highlight the cells you wish to amend and do a find and replace (crtl + f), where the find what:$$ and replace with:$ ... Depending in how many strings you are trying to edit this can be for larger quantities, much easier...